# Case statement vs If else in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

What is  main differences between if else and case statement in VHDL. Although both look similar and sometime replace each other.but What **logic circuit** appear after synthesis . **When should we** go for if else or case statement ?

Comment: This question can only be answered in detail with your synthesis tools "Synthesis Guide". Each vendor has documentation how VHDL statements are translated into logic. Both statement kinds have advantages and disadvantages. Normally, your synthesis tool should generate optimal code for both forms, so use what is better in readability and maintainability.

Comment: `if/then/elsif/else` can have unrelated conditions, `case` tests the same object against a set of values or ranges.

Comment: Case/selected signal assignment statements are required to have coverage for every value of the evaluated expression - choices. If/conditional signal assignment statements select the first valid condition  expression implying priority,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming an if-statement and a case-statement describes the same behavior, then the resulting circuit is likely to be identical after the synthesis tools done the translation and optimization.

As Paebbels writes in the comment, the details are described for each tool in the relevant synthesis guide, and there are probably tool-dependent cases where the result may differ, but as a general working assumption, then the synthesis tool will get to the same circuit for equivalent if-statements and case-statements.

The critical point is usually to make correct and maintainable VHDL code, and here readability counts, so **choose an if-statement or a case-statement depending on what makes the code most straight forward**, and don't try to control the resulting circuit through VHDL constructions, unless there is a specific reason that this is required.

Note that in the if-statement early conditions takes priority over later, but in the case-statement all `when` have equal priority.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that VHDL is parallel programming language and a form of declarative programming [see here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/declarative-vs-imperative-vs-procedural-programming) as opposed to procedural programming like c/c++ and another other sequential language.

This means in essence, you are telling or attempting to describe to the compiler with your code what the behavior should be, and not specifically telling it what to do or what the behavior is like with procedural programming. This might be what prompted you to ask the question.

Now remember however, that the sequencing of the if or case will affect synthesis. With FPGA's nowadays, all combinatorial part of the logic are in the form of Loop up tables which are internally designed as cascaded arrays multiplexers grouped together to form LUTs with input number N commonly 4 [See here for more details](https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8mqOgprTOAhUBL48KHY90C5AQFggiMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.altera.com%2Fen_US%2Fpdfs%2Fliterature%2Fwp%2Fwp-01003.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEWTE7OJDJ5b6IJEeW3wUOPN8N3gw&sig2=GyW0e32q4WCjDD57elnbCA&bvm=bv.129389765,d.c2I), and the compiler decides how to configure these arrays of LUTs.

The ordering can affect the number of cascaded multiplexer that the compiler calculates before the output is resolved.

Note that although in theory, it is possible to get the same behaviour for both if and switch. Case is looking at a single variable and deciding cases for each possible outcome while an If statement can be applied to multiple variables at the same time.

So flexibility? I would say goes to If. However with great power comes great responsibility, if is easy it use several signals from everywhere and if not done properly can lead to bad design, ie coupling of too many variable and any change is subject to failure due to too many dependency issues. Case is suitable for state machines but that is also true for procedural languages I suppose.

In addition, if you use too many different signals to act as conditions to your If, it can affect timing. which may mean limitation in your clock frequency, if you are working with high speed and the list goes on. clock skew, need to constrain signals etc.